# ¿Cómo puedo pasar a JSON el resultado de una búsqueda preparada con mysqli en PHP?

Tags: php, json, mysqli

Estoy tratando de pasara un resultado de una búsqueda pero no veo mi error, ¿podrían ayudarme?

El caso es que debo de hacer una consulta preparada y todos los resultados enviarlos a `JSON`, pero no veo cual es mi error.

```
$uss=$_REQUEST['uss'];
$pass=$_REQUEST['pass'];

if ($uss!=null and $pass!=NULL){
    echo "entro 1";
    $resultado = mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? and pasw=?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, "is", $uss, $pass);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($resultado);
}
else
{
    echo "error";

            }

echo json_encode($resultado);
?>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por sus sugerencias.

Comment: Pero que error te manda?

Comment: Según yo podría ser porque estás imprimiendo dos cosas ya sea el `echo "entro 1"` ó el `echo "error"` y a la vez el `echo json_encode($resultado)` revisalo y me cuentas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas tardes compañeros, apoyandome en sus respuestas y en el manual de php en linea encontre la respuesta y la comparto por si alguien alguna vez llega aqui cn esta duda:

```
$uss=$_REQUEST['uss'];
$pass=$_REQUEST['pass'];
if ($uss!=null and $pass!=NULL){
    //echo "entro 1";
    $resultado = mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? and passw=?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, "is", $uss, $pass);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($resultado);
    if(!$resultado or (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($resultado)==0)){}
    else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($resultado,$a1,$a2, $a3);
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($resultado)) {
        $datos=array($a1,$a2,$a3);}
        echo json_encode(array($datos));
        }
}
?>
```

¿Que pasaba? bueno, pues tal como me habian dicho estaba mandando varios echo que interferian, los elimine pero segui sin mandarme la información de la consulta, investigue en h[ttps://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php), y encontre esta información:

```
Ejemplo #1 Un ejemplo de json_encode()
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>

El resultado del ejemplo sería:

{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Así que con esta explicación obtuve el resultado y corri linea por linea en un while y los guarde en el arreglo $datos, despues pase el arreglo a JSON, tal como se ve aqui:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($resultado,$a1,$a2, $a3);
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($resultado)) {
        $datos=array($a1,$a2,$a3);}
        echo json_encode(array($datos));
```

lo interesante es que cualdo consumia el JSON me daba un dato falso, como si hubiera informacion cuando no la habia asi que decidi comprobar cuando la consulta estuviera vacia evitar que me apareciera el JSON con un NULL ya que al consumirlo eso me lo contaba como linea, asi que le puse una condicion

```
if(!$resultado or (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($resultado)==0)){}
    else {
```

y con eso resolvi mi problema.

Comment: considera que para mejorar la calidad de tu aporte y le sea de provecho a otros usuarios con las mismas dudas, deberás editar y explicar lo que hiciste o modificaste

Comment: tienes razón, voy a editar la respuesta

Comment: Gracias por la explicacion, tenia el mismo problema. Crack.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que mandar el echo dentro del `if`, además tienes que construir el formato de un JSON que corresponde a `"clave":"valor"` con un **array asociativo**, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```
$uss=$_REQUEST['uss'];
$pass=$_REQUEST['pass'];

if ($uss!=null and $pass!=NULL){
    //echo "entro 1";
    $resultado = mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? and pasw=?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, "is", $uss, $pass);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($resultado);

echo json_encode(array('Datos' => $resultado));

}
else
{
    echo "error";

            }

//echo json_encode($resultado);
?>
```

Cómo te comentan igual estás dando un `echo "entro 1"` si esto lo estás realizando por AJAX te va a traer un problema porque solo puedes mandar una respuesta del servidor y no 2 como en este caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias, en breve haré los cambios y les informaré

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que te comente y te reitera @Vick Muñoz, estás imprimiendo otras cosas además de la respuesta `JSON` por lo tanto va a generar conflicto y no lo tomará como un `JSON`, puedes solucionarlo como ya te dijeron anteriormente o simplemente hacerlo así:

```
$uss=$_REQUEST['uss'];
$pass=$_REQUEST['pass'];

if ($uss!=null and $pass!=NULL){
    //Quitas el echo "entro 1"
    $resultado = mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? and pasw=?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, "is", $uss, $pass);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($resultado);
    echo json_encode($resultado); //Mueves la respuesta aquí sin dejarla afuera de la condición
}
else
{
    echo "error";

}

?>
```

Y de esta manera, o imprime el error, o imprime la respuesta, pero no ambas, espero y te sirva